# Apache Spark - registering a UDF - returning dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF which returns a dataframe. Something like the one below

```
scala> predict_churn(Vectors.dense(2.0,1.0,0.0,3.0,4.0,4.0,0.0,4.0,5.0,2.0))
res3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [noprob: string, yesprob: string, pred: string]

scala> predict_churn(Vectors.dense(2.0,1.0,0.0,3.0,4.0,4.0,0.0,4.0,5.0,2.0)).show
+------------------+------------------+----+
|            noprob|           yesprob|pred|
+------------------+------------------+----+
|0.3619977592578127|0.6380022407421874| 1.0|
+------------------+------------------+----+
```

however when i try to register this as a UDF using the command

```
hiveContext.udf.register("predict_churn", outerpredict _)
```

i get an error like

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame is not supported
            at      org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:715)
```

Is returning dataframe not supported. I am using Spark 1.6.1 and Scala 2.10.  If this is not supported how can i return multiple columns to an external program please.

Thanks

Bala

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is returning dataframe not supported

Correct - you can't return a DataFrame from a UDF. UDFs should return types that are convertable into the supported column types:

- *Primitives* (Int, String, Boolean, ...)
- *Tuples* of other supported types
- *Lists, Arrays, Maps* of other supported types
- *Case Classes* of other supported types

In your case, you can use a case class:

```
case class Record(noprob: Double, yesprob: Double, pred: Double)
```

And have your UDF (`predict_churn`) return `Record`.
Then, when applied to a single record (as UDFs are), this case class will be converted into columns named as its members (and with the correct types), resulting in a DataFrame similar to the one currently returned by your function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tried that solution proposed by you. This is what i did

My case class is as follows
`case class Prob(noprob: String, yesprob: String, pred: String)`

In the function

`val op = result.map(p => Prob(p(0).toString, p(1).toString,p(2).toString))
op // returning op as the output
`

Even after this i get a very similar error

** scala> hiveContext.udf.register("predict_churn", outerpredict _)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Prob] is not supported
**

What am i doing wrong please..

Comment: Is your modified UDF now returning an _RDD_? That's not what I meant, it should just return a _Record_

Comment: I am sorry i am not getting the syntax correct. How can i convert 

`scala> result
res13: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [noprob: string, yesprob: string, pred: string]`

into a case class of type

`case class Record(noprob: String, yesprob: String, pred: String)`

Thanks

Comment: You can't/shouldn't convert a DataFrame into a Record.. I think you're misunderstanding the use of UDFs - UDFs are functions applied to a _single row_ (or subset of its columns) in a DataFrame, returning a value which is then converted into a different Row. UDFs are applied to _each record_ in a DataFrame (e.g. by `df.select(myUdf($"col1"))`) to produce a new DataFrame, but the UDF itself works at the single record level.